# Postgres quarter function

Tags: postgresql-9.4, postgres-9.6

When running

```
select to_char ("dateoftransfer", '"Q"quarter YYYY') as quarterly
FROM table;
```

I get back
`Q3uarter 2001` but expect `Q3 2001`

"dateoftransfer" is data type date

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this format:

```
select to_char(dateoftransfer, '"Q"Q YYYY')
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea you could do that

Comment: I'm trying to use this in conjunction with`INSERT INTO` but this doesn't work, is the syntax wrong?

Comment: @mappingdom . . . You should ask another question.